# Issue in JSON to Map formatting in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm pretty new in Flutter and I'm having some issues. I'm working on a simple Flutter app in which I get a JSON file from the internet, parse it to a Map, and display it. In a specific book object key from the JSON file, `publishedDate`, the value is another object named `$date` that has the actual publication date that I'm trying to access.

The issue is that, while I can access every object key and it's value, for some reason when I try to access `publishedDate.$date` I get `null` back. Given the fact that I can access any other object key and its value, I believe the issue is in the book model file, that parses the JSON to a Map.

**How would I got about fixing this?**

Here is the part where I believe the issue is. I'm also going to attach a part of the JSON file and the entire book model file.

```
class PublishedDate {

  String? $date;

  PublishedDate({this.$date});

  PublishedDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.$date = json["${$date}"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["${$date}"] = this.$date;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Entire Book Model**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class BookData {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? isbn;
  int? pageCount;
  PublishedDate? publishedDate;
  String? thumbnailUrl;
  String? shortDescription;
  String? longDescription;
  String? status;
  List<dynamic>? authors;
  List<dynamic>? categories;

  BookData({this.id, this.title, this.isbn, this.pageCount, this.publishedDate, this.thumbnailUrl, this.shortDescription, this.longDescription, this.status, this.authors, this.categories});

  BookData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json["_id"] == null ? null : json["_id"];
    this.title = json["title"];
    this.isbn = json["isbn"];
    this.pageCount = json["pageCount"];
    this.publishedDate = json["publishedDate"] == null ? null : PublishedDate.fromJson(json["publishedDate"]);
    this.thumbnailUrl = json["thumbnailUrl"];
    this.shortDescription = json["shortDescription"];
    this.longDescription = json["longDescription"];
    this.status = json["status"];
    this.authors = json["authors"] ?? [];
    this.categories = json["categories"] ?? [];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if(this.id != null)
      data["_id"] = this.id;
    data["title"] = this.title;
    data["isbn"] = this.isbn;
    data["pageCount"] = this.pageCount;
    if(this.publishedDate != null)
      data["publishedDate"] = this.publishedDate?.toJson();
    data["thumbnailUrl"] = this.thumbnailUrl;
    data["shortDescription"] = this.shortDescription;
    data["longDescription"] = this.longDescription;
    data["status"] = this.status;
    if(this.authors != null)
      data["authors"] = this.authors;
    if(this.categories != null)
      data["categories"] = this.categories;
    return data;
  }

  static getBooksAll() async{
    var bookURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/a-starck02/book_data/main/bookData_complex.json";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(bookURL));
    var listToPass = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<BookData> bookData = List<BookData>.from(listToPass.map((i) => BookData.fromJson(i)));
    return bookData;
  }
}

class PublishedDate {

  String? $date;

  PublishedDate({this.$date});

  PublishedDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.$date = json["${$date}"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["${$date}"] = this.$date;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**JSON File Sample**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "Unlocking Android",
    "isbn": "1933988673",
    "pageCount": 416,
    "publishedDate": {
      "$date": "2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700"
    },
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/ableson.jpg",
    "shortDescription": "Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide provides concise, hands-on instruction for the Android operating system and development tools. This book teaches important architectural concepts in a straightforward writing style and builds on this with practical and useful examples throughout.",
    "longDescription": "Android is an open source mobile phone platform based on the Linux operating system and developed by the Open Handset Alliance, a consortium of over 30 hardware, software and telecom companies that focus on open standards for mobile devices. Led by search giant, Google, Android is designed to deliver a better and more open and cost effective mobile experience.    Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide provides concise, hands-on instruction for the Android operating system and development tools. This book teaches important architectural concepts in a straightforward writing style and builds on this with practical and useful examples throughout. Based on his mobile development experience and his deep knowledge of the arcane Android technical documentation, the author conveys the know-how you need to develop practical applications that build upon or replace any of Androids features, however small.    Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide prepares the reader to embrace the platform in easy-to-understand language and builds on this foundation with re-usable Java code examples. It is ideal for corporate and hobbyists alike who have an interest, or a mandate, to deliver software functionality for cell phones.    WHAT'S INSIDE:        * Android's place in the market      * Using the Eclipse environment for Android development      * The Intents - how and why they are used      * Application classes:            o Activity            o Service            o IntentReceiver       * User interface design      * Using the ContentProvider to manage data      * Persisting data with the SQLite database      * Networking examples      * Telephony applications      * Notification methods      * OpenGL, animation & multimedia      * Sample Applications  ",
    "status": "PUBLISH",
    "authors": [
      "W. Frank Ableson",
      "Charlie Collins",
      "Robi Sen"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "Open Source",
      "Mobile"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "title": "Android in Action, Second Edition",
    "isbn": "1935182722",
    "pageCount": 592,
    "publishedDate": {
      "$date": "2011-01-14T00:00:00.000-0800"
    },
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/ableson2.jpg",
    "shortDescription": "Android in Action, Second Edition is a comprehensive tutorial for Android developers. Taking you far beyond \"Hello Android,\" this fast-paced book puts you in the driver's seat as you learn important architectural concepts and implementation strategies. You'll master the SDK, build WebKit apps using HTML 5, and even learn to extend or replace Android's built-in features by building useful and intriguing examples. ",
    "longDescription": "When it comes to mobile apps, Android can do almost anything   and with this book, so can you! Android runs on mobile devices ranging from smart phones to tablets to countless special-purpose gadgets. It's the broadest mobile platform available.    Android in Action, Second Edition is a comprehensive tutorial for Android developers. Taking you far beyond \"Hello Android,\" this fast-paced book puts you in the driver's seat as you learn important architectural concepts and implementation strategies. You'll master the SDK, build WebKit apps using HTML 5, and even learn to extend or replace Android's built-in features by building useful and intriguing examples. ",
    "status": "PUBLISH",
    "authors": [
      "W. Frank Ableson",
      "Robi Sen"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "Java"
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename $date to data

```
class PublishedDate {
  PublishedDate({
    required this.date,
  });

  final String date;

  factory PublishedDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PublishedDate(
        date: json["\u0024date"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "\u0024date": date,
      };
}
```